# How to lock a window height / width?

Tags: vim-windows, split

I jot notes in a tiny split window (buffer) regularly:

```
<C-W>s
:enew
:res 5
... jot jot...
```

When I create a new horizontal split in the same tab, that little window resizes, as if doing `<C-W>=`, which brings me to the question:

**Can I keep a split from resizing?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're like me, and came across this question when hoping to make a *particular* window have a fixed width (or height) *without* disabling `'equalalways'` and avoiding <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>, you should be aware of `'winfixwidth'` (or `'winfixheight'`):

```
'winfixheight' 'wfh'    boolean (default off), local to window
    Keep the window height when windows are opened or closed and
    'equalalways' is set.  Also for CTRL-W_=.  Set by default for the
    preview-window and quickfix-window.
    The height may be changed anyway when running out of room.
```

This is useful, for instance, in `terminal` windows; I use `setl wfw` in all of my vertical term-splits.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it more directly answers the question.

Comment: I guess since the command is `local to window` there is no need to use `setl`, so `set wfw` would also be fine

Answer (score 8):

If you read the doc for the command you use you will see [`:h CTRL-W_S`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#CTRL-W_S):

> Reduces the current window height to create room (and others, if the 'equalalways' option is set, 'eadirection' isn't "hor", and one of them is higher than the current or the new window).

So you can read [`:h 'equalalways'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27equalalways%27):

> When on, all the windows are automatically made the same size after splitting or closing a window.  This also happens the moment the option is switched on.  When off, splitting a window will reduce the size of the current window and leave the other windows the same.

So adding this to your vimrc should resolve your issue:

```
set noequalalways
```